# Asking about height of a human being

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

> A. How high is Mount Everest?
>   B. What is the height of Mount Everest?

Can we use the same sentence construction B when  we ask about the height of a human being?

> What is the height of Yuri Gagarin?

Answer (score 1):

For people, one usually asks

> How **tall** is Yuri Gagarin?

the answer might be

> He is 6 feet **tall**.
>   He is 6 feet in **height**.
>   His **height** is 6 feet.

Comment: Note that Yuri Gagarin was also famously very short (just over five feet tall) because the Soviets wanted to keep their first manned space capsule as small and lightweight as possible.  In such a case, where you already know that the person is notably short but don't know his exact height, you can also ask, **"How short is Yuri Gagarin?"**

Comment: *What is Yuri Gagarin's height* may also be suitable, at least more formally, if the asker is interested in the dimension and not the man: *what is Yuri Gagarin's height in centimenters?*